# Une nuance entre « Si ça se trouve » et « Qui sait »

Tags: expressions

I would say something like the following, using these two expressions, but I’m not sure if I correctly understand the nuances of meaning.

> **Si ça se trouve**, elle pourrait très bien le larguer en moins de temps qu'il ne faut pour le dire !
>
> **Qui sait** si elle ne va pas le larguer du jour au lendemain ?

***À mon avis :***

Dans ce cas précis, si ces deux expressions ont quelque chose en commun, c'est qu'elles servent à marquer le fait qu'il se peut qu'elle rompe avec lui sans signe avant-coureur.

Quant à « Si ça se trouve », je constate souvent qu'un locuteur fait exprès d'utiliser une expression exagérée, comme si quelque chose d'incroyable risquait d'arriver ! Et il s'agit de propos moqueurs et ironiques.

En revanche, je crois que l'on emploie « Qui sait » quand on dit sur un ton plus neutre qu'une chose pourrait éventuellement se produire.

Comment: Je ne vois pas vraiment de différence de sens entre les deux, par contre je constate qu'avec *qui sait*, la tournure devient négative ou utilise des termes contraires, pour exprimer le même fait. Exemple : *Si ça se trouve il est déjà mort* = *Qui sait s'il est encore vivant* = *Qui sait s'il n'est pas déjà mort*. C'est juste un truc que je viens de remarquer en réfléchissant, peut-être que ça n'a pas d'intérêt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le sens de ces expressions est essentiellement le même. Elles introduisent toutes deux des éventualités plutôt peu probables.

La différence principale tient au niveau de langue : « **qui sait** » est d'un registre élevé alors que « **si ça se trouve** » ne s'emploie qu'à l'oral et est d'un registre familier.

Comment: Personnellement j'utilise les deux. J'ai tendance à utiliser "Si ça se trouve" en début de phrase, et "qui sait ?" en fin de phrase. "Si ça se trouve, il est malade." ou "Il est peut-être malade, qui sait ?"